# connecting slots outside mainwindow class

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I have some GUI ( showing the bill in using `QTableWidget` ) which I have implemented outside the `MainWindow` class in my `checkout.cpp` file. I am having trouble in connecting slots inside the `checkout.cpp`.
 Since the `MainWindow` class inherits from the `QMainWindow`, I can associate the appropriate slot function with the this object.

How do I do this in the `CheckOut` class which does not inherit from Q`MainWindow` or `QWidget`?

**EDIT(CODE):**

```
CheckOut::CheckOut(string token)The CheckOut class does not inherit any other class. I am getting error: /home/sudeep/Desktop/mesonero project/mesonero-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/../mesonero/management.cpp:29: error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QPushButton*&, const char [11], Management* const, const char [8])'
{   CustomerToken = token;
   if(!findCustomer())
       QMessageBox::critical(0,QObject::tr("Check Out"),"Invalid Customer Token");
   else{
           generateBill();
           provideDiscount();
           QPushButton *payButton = new QPushButton("Pay");
           QObject::connect(payButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(deleteCustomer()));
           CustomerBill->layout()->addWidget(payButton);
       }
}

void CheckOut::deleteCustomer()
{
       DatabaseManager *dbm = DatabaseManager::Instance();

       QSqlQuery query("DELETE FROM `Residing_Customer` WHERE Customer_Token = '"+QString::fromStdString(CustomerToken)+"'",dbm->db);
       query.exec();
       CustomerBill->close();
}
```

**EDIT(ERROR):**

/`home/sudeep/Desktop/mesonero project/mesonero-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/../mesonero/checkout.cpp:29: error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QPushButton*&, const char [11], CheckOut* const, const char [8])'`

Comment: Signals/slots and inheritance aren't really related (apart from the fact that you need to inherit from QObject). It's not really clear what you're having problem with. Could you post some sample code you're not managing to get to work?

Comment: I suppose QMainWindow inherits QObject and hence connect(....,....,QObject*,...) can be executed if that class inherits from QMainWindow.

Comment: Anything that inherits from QObject can use signals and slots (emit or connect). I still don't understand what you're not managing. You've got a connect call in that code, what's preventing you from making that same connection between your other instances? (`payButton` and  `this` in the connect above are pointers to QObjects. That's the only thing you need for that. There's no need that one of those be `this` specifically.)

Comment: please look at the edit. I have added the error.

Comment: CheckOut _must_ inherit from QObject if you want to use signals and slots with it. (What edit?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use slots and signals you need to add `Q_OBJECT` in the private part of the class and inherits from `QObject`.

Any Qt class that you can use inherits from `QObject`, therefore if you are inheriting from a `QWidget` you are also inheriting from `QObject`.

```
class CheckOut : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
...
}
```

If you are passing a `QObject*` parent to your `CheckOut` constructor you may want to build the `QObject` subobject with that parent as well:

```
CheckOut::CheckOut(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) { ... }
```

Comment: What about the constructor implemenation, do I need to make some changes there?

Comment: @sudeepdino008, if you are passing a `QObject*` parent to the `CheckOut` constructor you may want to construct the `QObject` object with that parent aswell. (see the edit for a complete example)